# UITextView Cursor Placement at the top

Tags: ios

I have a UITextView with some text already present in it. When I make this textview as the first responder, I used the following code to place the cursor on the first line

```
messageTextView.selectedRange=NSMakeRange(0, 0);

[messageTextView becomeFirstResponder];
```

What I want is to place the cursor above the first line of the text(Give a 1 line gap between the existing text and the cursor).

Comment: Above the first line? How is that possible?

Comment: i meant to place the cursor on the first line and the existing text on the second line( its for implementing reply to a message in a messaging app)

Comment: So do you want to prepend some text as well?

Comment: Just place the cursor on the first line so that the user can start typing the reply message. The original message would remain

Comment: @userXXX so doesn't the code above work?

Answer (score 1):

Prepend a newline character just before your two lines of code:

```
    NSString *tempString = messageTextView.text;
    messageTextView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n%@", tempString]];

    messageTextView.selectedRange=NSMakeRange(0, 0);

    [messageTextView becomeFirstResponder];
```